# Why does swank-js give me "document is not defined" in the emacs REPL?

Tags: javascript, slime, swank

I follow these steps:

1. Run swank-js in the command line.
2. Run emacs.
3. M-x slime-connect.
4. Host: 127.0.0.1; Port: 4005
5. Open up the `http://localhost:8009/swank-js/test.html` in Firefox.
6. Receive: "Remote attached: (browser) Firefox14.0" in the emacs REPL.
7. Run the command "document" in the REPL.

At this point, I receive the error:

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at repl:1:1
    at DefaultRemote.evaluate (/usr/lib/nodejs/swank-js/swank-handler.js:314:9)
    at Executive.listenerEval (/usr/lib/nodejs/swank-js/swank-handler.js:414:21)
    at Handler.receive (/usr/lib/nodejs/swank-js/swank-handler.js:169:20)
    at SwankParser.onMessage (/usr/lib/nodejs/swank-js/swank.js:50:17)
    at SwankParser.handleMessage (/usr/lib/nodejs/swank-js/swank-protocol.js:75:8)
    at SwankParser.handleContent (/usr/lib/nodejs/swank-js/swank-protocol.js:62:10)
    at SwankParser.execute (/usr/lib/nodejs/swank-js/swank-protocol.js:53:20)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/swank-js/swank.js:60:16)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:67:17)
```

Should I be using require() or something?  I'm still a bit hazy how swank/slime/node are communicating so please forgive the black box nature of this question. :D

Comment: By the way, if you haven't already seen this.  I thought you might appreciate it: http://emacsrocks.com/e11.html

Comment: Thanks! That's actually the reason I started to try JavaScript and swank-js. I believe the problem had to do with me creating a symlink within the slime directory (to swank-js), and then, for some reason, changing out my slime-js file? But, the short of it is to ensure your slime-js file is correct. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by the bug report at https://github.com/swank-js/swank-js/issues/49#issuecomment-8079040, I'd guess you aren't loading the slime-js component.

Comment: This was correct - I had an error loading slime-js. (I will award the bounty when the time limit expires.)  Thanks for your help!